# Access Panda index in apply function to create html

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have panda Series with index as product name and values as its rate. I want to create string as below

Product Name  Product rate

Currently I am using for loop
for p,v in srs.items():
some_var='<font ...>' + p + '' + '%.2f' % v + ''

Can I do above code without for loop like using apply or any other way. I tried apply but not able to access index in apply. I don't feel converting to dataframe and then using apply is a good idea.
There is one more reason I am avoiding for as I think for will be slower than apply and also its not elegant

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
srs = srs.to_frame()
srs['some_var'] = '<font ...>' + srs.index + '' + '%.2f' % srs['column_name'] + ''
```

Where `'column_name'` is the name of the column after transforming the series to a DataFrame.

Comment: Can we do it without converting to dataframe?